# RCP e4 application first start need several seconds

Tags: e4

I developed an e4 rcp application and the application need several seconds (ca. 25-35) to open the login dialog. If I restart it it needs only 2-3 seconds.

I think that the main part is still stored in the RAM but my questions is can I improve the first start of my application and how?

Answer (score 0):

> can I improve the first start of my application [...]?

Not to my knowledge, no. It sounds like the first start is initializing the cache for the OSGi framework and Eclipse runtime (bundle dependency resolution and extension registry data). You can verify this by starting your application with the command line argument `-clean` or the system property `osgi.clean`.

Documentation for `osgi.clean`: https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html#osgiclean